# Split a row into n rows then merge rows in other column in to 1 [python]

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a record like this:

```
Name .... Email Address
Alex .... alex1@gmail.comalex2@gmail.comalex3@gmail.com
Peter.... peter1@gmail.com
```

I want to use panda in order to split 1 alex1@gmail.comalex2@gmail.comalex3@gmail.com into 3 rows then merge blank rows Alex (name) into 1 like this:

```
Name .... Email Address
     .... alex1@gmail.com
Alex .... alex2@gmail.com
     .... alex3@gmail.com
Peter.... peter1@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex pattern with .split() and method chaining:

Code:

```
df = (df
      .assign(Email=df["Email Address"].str.split(pat=r"(?<=com)"))
      .explode(column=["Email"])
      .query(expr="~Email.eq('')")
      .drop(columns=["Email Address"])
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name             Email
0   Alex   alex1@gmail.com
1   Alex   alex2@gmail.com
2   Alex   alex3@gmail.com
3  Peter  peter1@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you missed to provide some very important information:

- Is the email always gmail.com?
- there is never separation characte?

Assuming that the answer is always yes, I would go with the following solution:

1. First, iterate through all the rows in pandas
2. Extract the name and email address
3. Find all the matches of the extracted (and lowered) name in the email addresses using regex
4. Creating a list with the names and extracted email addresses and creating a temporary dataframe of these
5. Concatenating all dataframes

As there is no sample file attached, I tried to create a similar file and here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

final_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name","Email"])
email_pattern="@gmail.com"
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    name_pattern=df.loc[index,"Name"].lower()
    email_string=df.loc[index,"Email"].lower()
    match = re.findall(fr'{name_pattern}\d*{email_pattern}', email_string)
    my_list=[[name_pattern.capitalize(),x] for x in match]
    new_df=pd.DataFrame(data=my_list,columns=["Name","Email"])
    final_df=pd.concat([final_df, new_df], axis=0)
```

If it works, please accept this solution as answer to your post.

Output dataframe:

[image]